# LINQ : Get the last record which referer list is not null c#

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-web-api

I have created a table using Code First

```
public class TechnicalData
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int MarketId { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Product> Products{ get; set; }
    public TechnicalData()
    {
        Products= new Collection<Product>();
    }
}
```

and in my api i will return the last record base on the marketId

```
 public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetTechnicalData(int id)
    {
      
        TechnicalData technicalData = await db.TechnicalDatas.Include("Products").OrderByDescending(t => t.Id).FirstOrDefaultAsync(t => t.MarketId == id);
        return Ok(technicalData);
    }
```

But the problem is i actually want to return this data only if the Products list is not null. If it is null i want to get the last TechnicalData which Products list is not null. How can i do that?

Thanks on advance

Comment: `.Where(z=> z.Products.Any())`?

Comment: Yes. That solved my problem. Thanks :)